# jquery / jqtouch getJSON call causing infinite loop?

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson, jqtouch

Writing my first JQTouch app. When I go from `#login` to `#home`, a JSON ajax call happens successfully but the `pageAnimationEnded` event appears to be in an infinite loop.

```
        $(function(){

            $('#login').ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {                
                jQT.goTo('#home', 'flip'); 
            }); 

            $('#home').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function(e, info){

                alert('animation ended'); //infinite loop happens in here

                $.getJSON('/test', function(data) {
                     alert('json: ' + data); //this returns data successfully
                });

            });

        });
```

Login POST call which JQuery intercepts and turns into AJAX:

```
  <div id="login" class="current">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>testapp</h1>
            <a class="button slideup" id="infoButton" href="#about">About</a>
        </div>
        <form:form commandName="user" action="/login/authenticate">
            <ul class="edit rounded">
                <li><form:input path="email"/></li>
                <li><form:password path="password" /></li>                    
                <li>Remember Me<span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" /></span></li>                    
            </ul>
           <a style="margin:0 10px;color:rgba(0,0,0,.9)" href="" class="submit whiteButton">Login</a>
        </form:form>
    </div>
```

Any hints would be appreciated, thanks in advance! :-)

**UPDATE**

Apparently .ajaxComplete recieves events for other elements as well. I added a guard to filter the event that I want:

```
         $(document).ready(function(e){
              alert('document ready');

              $('#login').ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {      

                  if(settings.url == '/login/authenticate') { //add check to prevent infinite loop
                      alert('jqt goto ' + settings.url);          
                      jQT.goTo('#home', 'flip'); 
                  }
             }); 

             $('#home').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function(e, info){

                alert('animation ended');

                $.getJSON('/test', function(data) {
                     alert('json: ' + data);
                });

             });
        });
```

Comment: I think that's a rather roundabout solution.  Again, as I mentioned below, I'd avoid an all encompassing ajaxComplete call (for performance issues if nothing else, since this gets called on EVERY ajax call) and just provide a callback to the initial #login ajax call (wherever that exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya this will definitely cause an infinite loop.  Assuming that the initial `pageAnimationEnd` is somehow triggered, Here's what you're doing:

Animation ends, so your bind method does an ajax call.  That ajax call has a callback registered on completion `ajaxComplete()` that says "go home".  This go home presumably does some sort of animation, which, on complete triggers your ajax call.  That ajax call has a callback registered on completion `ajaxComplete()` that says "go home"...  and on and on.

Likely what you want is not a generic `ajaxComplete()` which gets called on all ajax requests, but a specific one on your login code that does a single call.  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve though so it's hard to give you a solution to the problem.  This should be a sufficient explanation to your problem though if I understand everything correctly

Comment: Thanks Brad. Yeah you're definitely right. I added conditional logic but I'm not sure this is the a scalable way to address more of these flows in the future. Is there a .ajaxComplete that will only fire for specific elements? What I want to do is have a specific handler for each element within JQTouch.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jqTouch.  I'm also having a hard time understanding where your login ajax call takes place, can you post more code?

Comment: Sorry, I left it out for brevity. I just updated the page. It's a standard form POST but jquery of course intercepts that and makes it an AJAX call.

Comment: where's the code that actually intercepts the form login?  ie `$("#login form").submit(function(){ // do SOmeting });`

Comment: When I was debugging it with firefox, it looked like it was within the jquery.js library itself. Mine is minified so it's pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very good with JQuery but I think you could use the `$(selector).one(function(){...}` to prevent a loop.

http://api.jquery.com/one/